# Swift remove element dictionary and reload tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a dictionary and Product in CoreData:

```
var productSortArray: [Date:[Product]?] = [:]
var productArray = [Product]()
```

Here's my numberOfRowsInSection:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (productSortArray[dateArray[section]]!!.count)
}
```

When I delete row in commit editingStyle, i update:

```
self.productArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)                
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
tableView.reloadData()
```

But, when delete row and reload table, the number of rows is incorrect and have a problem:

> The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

Comment: This is confusing. You show two properties `productSortArray` and `productArray`. But then your `numberOfRowsInSection` is based on `productSortArray` and `dateArray`. And lastly you update `productArray` when you remove a row. None of these match.

Comment: Probably unrelated but **never** call `reloadData()` right after `insertRows/deleteRows`. You get rid of the animation and `insertRows/deleteRows` does update the UI.

Comment: dateArray is array of Date :(

Comment: How remove element dictionary in this case? Thanks bro.

Comment: You might have to remove `productSortArray[dateArray[indexPath.section]]!!.remove(at: indexPath.row)`. I highly recommended to use a `class` (with reference semantics) for this design.

Comment: Unrelated by your use of `!!` is a crash waiting to happen.

Comment: `productSortArray` is not updated when you remove , so of course `numberOfRowsInSection` is incorrect

Comment: @Vadian thanks bro, and when i remove all row in section, how to remove this section?

Comment: @Carpsen i know that but i dont know how to remove element dictionary...

Comment: @rmaddy im newbie and thanks for your help :D

Comment: Set the dictionary key to `nil` and use `deleteSections(:with:)` and don't forget to remove the key also in `dateArray`.

Comment: @vadian Thank you very much <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of dealing with arrays and a dictionaries, you'll find it much easier if you create objects that actually represent your data…

```
struct ProductSection {
    let date: Date
    var products: [Product]
}

var sections: [ProductSection] = // Initialise this
```

then

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[section].products.count 
}
```

then to delete a row…

```
sections[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```